# Having external django application using bootstrap without touching templates?

Tags: django

I am using `django-allauth` application. It has got many views built-in, but none has been configured to use `bootstrap` (ie, `CSS` `class="form-control"` is missing in forms).

There are many python libraries to add this `CSS` class in forms (`django-bootstrap4`, `django-widget-tweaks`, `django-bootstrap-form`, etc...) but all of these require to have access to the template in order to add specific tags or filters.

As `django-allauth` has got many views, I do not want to override all corresponding templates to add these specific tags/filters; It will be a lot of work and will be awful to maintain when upgrading to another `django-allauth` version.

Actually, the only solution I found is to write a middleware that parses and patches `HTML` code to add `bootstrap` `CSS` classes. It works with all views without having to touch any templates. The main drawback is that it is `CPU` expensive.

Do you know a library that can add `bootstrap` `CSS` classes to forms without having to modify templates and is not based on `HTML` parsing ?

Comment: possibly crispy forms?

Comment: Unfortunately not : it requires access to the template to use crispy tag